# Setting Up Postman for API Testing When Using Passport Authorization

Tags: node.js, rest, passport.js, restful-authentication, postman

I am a bit confused while trying to get Postman to work when testing the API of my application. Namely, I am using Passport authentication; however, I do not know which type it defaults to or uses in my code. How can I figure this out and which type should I choose in Postman?

Here is the relevant Passport code:

```
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport, path, nodemailer, sesTransport, EmailTemplate, templateDir, template){

    // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        //console.log('serializing user: ');console.log(user);
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            //console.log('deserializing user:',user);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
    login(passport);
    signup(passport, path, nodemailer, sesTransport, EmailTemplate, templateDir, template);

}
```

Lastly, pretty much all of my API points only work when the user is logged in. How can I emulate the same behavior in Postman by saving the authorization credentials?

**Edit:**

```
Perhaps this code is relevant as well:


module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true,
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) { 
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'email' :  username }, 
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                    }
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                    // User and password both match, return user from done method
                    // which will be treated like success
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            );

        })
    );


    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which type of passport authentication strategy are you using ? Most people use passport-http-bearer.

Comment: How can I determine it? I have looked in the code and there does not seem to be any parameter for that.

Comment: Could it be passport-local?

Answer (score 11):

I don't have a code that runs local auth strategy but I think the following postman setup should work for you.

To request for an access token; assuming your endpoint is auth/local.

1. open up Postman
2. create a POST request
3. under authorization tab set "No Auth"
4. under body tab -> click on x-www-form-urlencoded
5. add a key named email and enter the user email
6. add a key named password and enter the associated secret for the email

**See token request screenshot below:**

[image: localAuthentication]

The response will come back with an access_token.

To use the access_token simply create a HTTP request and in the HEADER tab, add the key Authorization followed by a value of "Bearer

**See use token request screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: @MadPhysicist let me know whether this works for you.

Comment: What is the "associated email secret" that you are referring to?

Comment: I have tried the first part of your suggestion. On the login page, I have two text fields: email and password. Those are the keys and values that I pre-fill when doing a POST request. However, it returns (with code 200) and seems to return the entire login page (HTML form )back to me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what gets returned from your login end point is determined by your own code. Passport only performs the authentication and tells your app whether that user performing the auth is valid or not. Typically your code would go on to generate a unique access token and pass it back as a response to the user. Then this token would be use by the user to represent him in subsequent request. Check the code in your endpoint. I suspect you will have something like `res.redirect('login-page-url')`

Comment: "Associated email secret" - I meant the user's passport.

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it works fine in postman.
After getting response of access token
under the Authorization tab. select "Bearer Token" from "Type" drop-down. and Token with field will appear on right. enter the access token.

This works fine with Laravel REST APIs.

**Check Screen Shot**
[Postman Auth Token passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMxIj.png)

Answer (score 1):

What I did is. First send the login request thru postman. If you look in the response you should see a cookies tab. Copy the value of the cookie

[Postman Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMUU9.png)

When you want to check the "protected" route in the headers you need to choose cookie and in value paste the value you have copied before.

[Cookie Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duMUh.png)

Answer (score 0):

when we use passport js it stores the user information using sessions, there is a bug in express-session. so by using cookie-session it is solved ( for me ) because it gives a header parameter `cookie`, which we can use in postman for testing.
when we are in the browser it automatically sets the cookies in the header but for the postman, we have manually do it.
we will get the cookie info form `req`  in express ex:

[image]

which we can use in postman like :

[image]